# CodeIgniter 2 Call autoloaded model

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is probably a newb question but how do I call a model that has been auto loaded?

I had:

```
$this->load->model('Test'); 
$data['members'] = $this->Test->get_members();
```

But now I don't need to load it since it's auto loaded. I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined property: Members::$Test
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally you have to load your model, if autoloaded not:

```
$this->load->model('test');
```

If you've a function in your model like:

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model {
    function get_members(){
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

You can load this and put it in a var to send it to a view:

```
$data['members'] = $this->test_model->get_members();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it right, except you don't capitalize class names when calling them and also make sure you include the full model name (with _model if it's called `Test_model`):

```
$this->load->model('test_model'); 
$data['members'] = $this->test_model->get_members();
```